# How to make it so linear-gradient does not repeat

Tags: css

I have the following css:

```
header {
  background-color: #5A775A;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: 20px;
}

html {
  /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #5A775A 100%);

  /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #5A775A 100%);

  /* Opera */ 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #5A775A 100%);

  /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #000000), color-stop(1, #5A775A));

  /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 0%, #5A775A 100%);

  /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 0%, #5A775A 100%);
}
```

Which is producing the following design:

[image]

As you can see the gradient is repeating. How do I make it so it does not repeat vertically, and it is just one long gradient across the entire page?

EDIT:

Trying to use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Produces:

[image]

The problem with this is it does not span across the entire screen.

Comment: For CSS gradients, preferrably use just `background` than `background-image`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Tried everything and this was the one that worked. Thanks alot buddy

Answer (score 0):

With `background-repeat: no-repeat;` add: `background-size: cover;`